# Why Style.Resources requires x:Key

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

Why does WPF not allow me to add a resource without x:Key to `Style.Resources` section? When I try the following:

```
<DataTemplate>
  ...
  <Style TargetType="X">
    <Style.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="Y">
        ...
      </DataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
  </Style>
</DataTemplate>
```

it raises the following compile-time error:

```
All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.
```

The same resource can be added to a UserControl's Resources section.

Comment: are you saving these styles somewhere using dictionary>

Comment: @Clemens: Did you add both `Style` and `DataTemplate` without `x:Key` and is the `DataTemplate` inside `Style.Resources`? This thing is not compiling for me!

Comment: Yes, I have a DataTemplate without Key in Style.Resources of a default Style (also without Key) in Window.Resources.

Comment: @Clemens: I see. My `Style` itself is embedded inside another `DataTemplate` (also without any `x:Key` and `DataType`). If I remove `Style.Resources` section from the inner `DataTemplate`, it all compiles fine, but if I add this section, it shows error on the **outer** `DataTemplate` node. Any idea why? (I'm updating the question accordingly)